# Native (python stdin) app not receiving Chrome sendNativeMessage (stdout) output

Tags: python, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I am attempting to send some data to my native Python app via the Chrome sendNativeMessage function, but so far have been unsuccessful.

**Below is my Javascript:**

```
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
         var email = {text:request};

         alert(email["text"]) // showing that i successfully received message

         chrome.runtime.sendNativeMessage('com.whatever.whatever.xyz',
         email[0],
          function(response) {
            console.log("Received " + response);
          });

});
```

**Below is my Python:**

```
import win32com.client
import struct
import sys
import json
import datetime
import time

# On Windows, the default I/O mode is O_TEXT. Set this to O_BINARY
# to avoid unwanted modifications of the input/output streams.
import os, msvcrt
msvcrt.setmode(sys.stdin.fileno(), os.O_BINARY)
msvcrt.setmode(sys.stdout.fileno(), os.O_BINARY)

# Read the message length (first 4 bytes).
#for line in sys.stdin:
text_length_bytes = sys.stdin.read(4)

# Unpack message length as 4 byte integer.
#text_length = struct.unpack('i', text_length_bytes.encode('utf-8'))[0]
text_length = struct.unpack('i', text_length_bytes)[0]

# Read the text of the message.
#text = sys.stdin.read(text_length)
text = sys.stdin.read(text_length).decode('utf-8')

olMailItem = 0x0

obj = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")

newMail = obj.CreateItem(olMailItem)
newMail.Subject = "Whatever"
newMail.HTMLBody = text

newMail.display()
```

Weirdly, I can successfully send hard-coded values by tweaking the Python a bit (see the commented-out "text_length =" and "text =" lines) and changing the Javascript to pass { text: "Hello world!" } instead of email[0].  But when I pass an object, it fails.

I feel like I'm missing something fundamental here.  Can someone help me understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var email = {text:request};

// ...
  email[0]
// ...
```

Isn't really an array, is it?